# An instance of analyzer cannot be created System.Runtime 7.0.0.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm was trying to play around with source generators in .net7 but am stuck on this error:
System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0 - The system cannot find the file specified..

CSC : warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer generator.RepoGenerator cannot be created from E:\git\dotnetExamples\dn7-source-generators\generator\bin\Debug\net7.0\generator.dll : Could not load file or assembly **'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,** PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

I have tried updating my SDK version and to try and match with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp
but cannot figure it out.

This is the repo I have used to test:

https://github.com/CharlieDigital/dn7-source-generators

**Generator.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Environment**:

VS2022
Version 17.7.4

SDK
.net 7.0.401

I can see that dotnet build works so for some reason building in Visual Studio is causing this.

Comment: The version of the analyzer is not the one inside Net 7.0.  The best way of adding the reference is from Visual Studio menu.  Make sure your target is Net 7.0 and then use menu Project : Add Reference which does not specify version.  Visual Studio will add the correct version.  I would use Solution explorer and delete the reference from project.  Then use Project : Add Menu to put back into project.